# Pivot table from horizontal to vertical

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

i have a following table of results:

[image: Example of current SQL table]

What i want is a resulted table with following structure:

[image: Final table]

Is any posibility to do that with SQL?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT (SQL query with exampled temp table):

```
        CREATE TABLE #FINAL_STACK
        (
            FB_DATE datetime,
            FB_DESC VARCHAR(200)
        )

        INSERT INTO #FINAL_STACK(FB_DATE, FB_DESC)
        SELECT '2017-03-09', 'D - FIZ: 1'
        UNION
        SELECT '2017-03-09', 'D - PRI: 1'
        UNION      
        SELECT '2017-03-10', 'D - FIZ: 1'
        UNION
        SELECT '2017-03-10', 'D - PRI: 1'
        UNION
        SELECT '2017-03-13', 'D - FIZ: 2'
        UNION
        SELECT '2017-03-13', 'D - PRI: 1'
        UNION
        SELECT '2017-03-13', 'D - TEPAP: 1'

        SELECT * FROM #FINAL_STACK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DynammicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@DynamicPIVOTColumns NVARCHAR(MAX);


SET @DynamicPIVOTColumns = STUFF
                            (
                                (
                                SELECT ',[' + CAST([FB_DATE] AS VARCHAR(12)) + ']'
                                FROM #FINAL_STACK
                                GROUP BY [FB_DATE]
                                ORDER BY [FB_DATE]
                                FOR XML PATH('') ,TYPE
                                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                                ,1
                                ,1
                                ,''
                            );

SET @DynammicTSQLStatement = N'
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT *
     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  FB_DATE ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RID
FROM #FINAL_STACK
) DS
PIVOT
(
    MAX([FB_DESC]) FOR [FB_DATE] IN (' + @DynamicPIVOTColumns + ')
) PVT';


EXEC sp_executesql @DynammicTSQLStatement;
```

[image]

We need to perform dynamic pivot in order to be sure it will always work for different days. Also, note we are creating a row ID column using `ROW_NUMBER` in order to ensure all records for particular date are displayed. Otherwise, you will get only one value (for example the min or the max) depending on the `PIVOT` aggregate function.